# Dual/Range fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a portal which requires timetable in a model.

Firstly, I wanted to make it a dictionary or array, but due to my research I abandoned this idea. Now I wish to make 7 fields (1 for each week day), each field should consist of start time and end time. Of course I could simply make twice as much fields, but that looks really repulsively in an admin panel.

My question: is there a field type, that would provide a range field? Something like: Label: [    ] - [    ]? I'd need to also make something similar for price range.

Comment: "that looks really repulsively in an admin panel" can you post your ModelAdmin source code ? Did you try to "display multiple fields on the same line, wrap those fields in their own tuple. In this example, the url and title fields will display on the same line and the content field will be displayed below them in its own line" ?

Comment: In general, try to separate the data model from the representation in the template. Define the data model as it makes most sense and then abstract that for your users in the template. For your uses case: diplay it as [start]-[end], not matter how it looks like in the database.

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid modeling admin panel, but seems that I'll have to :P. Thanks for help =).